# Not using Web Server for html pages

Tags: webserver

For an intranet application instead of using a proper web server, it has been planned to just deploy static html pages by sharing it over the network. This static html page is continously updated in the background by a program running on that PC and people access this html page by typing the shared file path directly in the browser. A maximum of 10 simultaneous users are expected to access it.
Can any one see the disadvantages or advantages in this type of deployment?

Comment: what happens when the write process locks the file? If this is supposedly static content why is it constantly being updated.
This sounds like a case for caching.

Comment: Would we not still have read access for users?

Comment: They might, but normally opening a file for writing locks the file. Even if they do what version of the file do they get the new or old or a mix of the two. I agree with Bobby that this is really the wrong approach. You may be able to put a screw in the wall with a hammer, but it doesn't make it the right tool for the job. I would be curious to know the rational behind your decision not to use a web server and scripting language.

Comment: We are short of developers and there is no option to increase the same as of now. So we were trying to reduce the amount of code base that needs to be maintained and also minimize different number of technologies and languages we use. We already have a tool to process data and is capable of generating an html file. Even though I knew what is being attempted is not a good way, I could not find any points against this method which I could put forward to the managers. With sufficient arguments I can push for a solution similar to Bobby's and push for more resource too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that this is what Web server side programming languages are designed to solve. One disadvantage is that this makes the process overly complicated. Web servers can be pretty light weight if the issue is not wanting extra administrative overhead. It sounds like you'd be writing a lot of data unnecessarily. I'd suggest using some Web based programming language/platform like PHP, Perl, ASP.NET, etc to just serve up content.